# Pytorch - Efficient Elementwise Multiply?

Tags: pytorch

I have a tensor of 3D Points of [100x3]

I have a vector of weights of [100x1], which needs to be element wise multiplied into the X,Y,Z coordinates.

Currently, I am creating a new vector W where I stack the [100x3] element with repetition into a [100x3] tensor, before i do an element wise multiply.

I need to do this many times, and this is way too slow and memory intensive. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Standard multiplication (`*`) in PyTorch already is elementwise. Additionally, it [broadcasts](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/notes/broadcasting.html). So

```
import torch
xyz = torch.randn(100, 3)
w = torch.randn(100, 1)
multiplied = xyz * w
```

will just do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for this!